# Laravel filter & authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller that handles query filters, now that a part of the filter requires the users to be logged in in order to apply the filter. What is the best approach for this? appreciate any help! thank you very much!

API route:
Route::get('toyslist','toyslistController@index');

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Toylist;

class ToyslistController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $toyslist = (new Toylist)->newQuery();

        if($request->has('type')){
            $toy_typeArray = explode(',',$request->type);
            $toyslist->whereIn('type',$toy_typeArray);
        }

        if($request->has('age')){
            $toy_ageArray = explode(',',$request->type);
            $toyslist->whereIn('age',$toy_ageArray);
        }

        if($request->has('brand')){
            $toy_brandArray = explode(',',$request->type);
            $toyslist->whereIn('brand',$toy_brandArray);
        }

        if($request->has('storage')){
            if(Auth::check()){
                $toy_storageArray = explode(',',$request->type);
                $toyslist->whereIn('storage',$toy_storageArray);
            }
        }

        return $toyslist->paginate(15);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: with the Route::get the Auth::check() or Auth::id() always returns empty, i do not want to use middleware in the route to block the public use of filters. is there a way to go about this or do i have to replicate the same method with route middleware and leave this to non route middleware?

Comment: The only thing I would change is to put the auth check in the check above it e.g. `if ($request->has('storage') && Auth::check()) {` .

Comment: The `Auth::check()` should not return `false` unless the user isn't signed in. Are you using the `web` middleware on your request or is this an API route?

Comment: Just checking, but I'm assuming that `$request->type` isn't meant to be used inside all of the if statements?

Comment: this is in the Api route

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what are you getting at? Ross

Comment: @NewProgrammer He is referring to all of the if-statements using `$request->type` as their explode arguement.

Also by default the API authentication is different from the Web authentication, that is why you're getting a null / false response.

Comment: the if $request is meant to be used that way, as frontend is using localhost/api/toyslist?brand=1,2,3&age=5,9

Comment: You are using the same input for all of the arrays. Effectively doing the following

`localhost/api/toyslist?type=1,2,3&age=5,9`

then your type and age array would return this

`type: 1,2,3`
`age: 1,2,3`

Comment: yes, it is to be able to use whereIn to query. But the problem about Auth facade functions is still there. Any idea what will be a better approach?

Comment: By default the API routes, do not start a session as they are stateless. An API is supposed to be stateless - and isn't supposed to rely on sessions. If you want to use session based authentication, then use the Web guard for your routes.

Comment: Yes, Toyslist is part of API and is stateless. But only a specific filter needs the user to be logged in. if i do not use session based authentication, how else should i approach the situation?

Comment: @NewProgrammer You could use something like [Laravel's Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport)

Comment: I have already implemented passport, the login is based on passport

Answer (score 0):

For now I did the following to make it work:

Added API route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('protectedtoyslist','toyslistController@index');
Route::get('toyslist','toyslistController@index');
```

So the frontend uses `localhost/api/toyslist` to filter thru the products without storage filter for users who did not login.

For logged in users the frontend uses `localhost/api/protectedtoyslist` to filter products which includes storage filter.

Very much appreciate if anyone has a better approach for this. Thanks!